# How do I get HTTP Reason Phrase from SuperAgent/node?

Tags: node.js, superagent

How do I get a "Reason Phrase" (such as `OK` in `HTTP/1.1 200 OK`, etc) using SuperAgent (or raw node.js http)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Retrieving the reason phrase/status message is only [available since node v0.11.10](https://github.com/joyent/node/commit/7ffe2ad) (unstable). For node v0.10.x (stable) or older you're out of luck.

Comment: Interesting... So how does the browser get hold of it (in Chrome it can be found next to the request status on the network tab)?

Comment: @Charlie it's not that node wasn't parsing it before, it's just that it wasn't making it publicly available before node v0.11.10.